# Start-Job not producing expected output

Tags: powershell, scripting

Why, in the code below, does the Read-Host line's output display before the job's output?

```
$WorkingDirectory = Get-Location

$ScriptBlockForJob = {    
    Get-ChildItem $Input -Directory `
        | Where-Object `
            {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0 -and $_.GetDirectories().Count -eq 0} `
                | Select-Object FullName                
}

Start-Job -InputObject $WorkingDirectory -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockForJob | Wait-Job | Receive-Job 

Read-Host 'Above is a list of empty directories. Press enter to begin deleting them'
```

[The code above yields this ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGkVz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead you remove the last line in `$ScriptBlockForJob`, the command will run as expected.

```
$ScriptBlockForJob = {    
    Get-ChildItem $Input -Directory `
        | Where-Object `
            {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0 -and $_.GetDirectories().Count -eq 0}                               
}
```

[Output as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUTpy.png)